# Why am I getting this weird Android error, even though it appears to have no effect on my app?

Tags: android

I have an app with a simple group chat function. When a chat is received, I show a toast and play a sound, like so:

```
Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(mainActivity.getApplicationContext(), RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
ringtone.play();
```

This code is not in my MainActivity, or any other activity for that matter. It is in a thread that is started in the MainActivity. I passed a reference of MainActivity into the thread at start-up so I could do things like this, toasts, and such.

This works perfectly. Whenever a chat comes in, the notification sound is heard loud and clear.

My issue is this. In the logcat in AndroidStudio, I am getting this error:

```
E/MediaPlayer: Uri is content://settings/system/notification_sound
```

Like the title says, it appears to have no affect on my app, but I am worried that something is wrong, and that it could break my app in the future.

Do I need to worry about this? If so, how do I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure this is an error ? How did you get to that conclusion?

Comment: I was under the assumption that **E/** was an error in logcat. Am I incorrect?